# In which part of iOS is the auto-erase feature implemented and how does it work?

Tags: ios, security, encryption, privacy, firmware

I followed the Apple vs FBI case a bit, and I'm super curious how Apple implemented the auto-erase feature. Reading their documentation, it seems like it is as simple as erasing a key that is used to encrypt all the data. Is it actually a microkernel or something?

Comment: Please add the link you are refering to.

Answer (score 1):

When a wipe occurs, the file system key is deleted. It's as simple as that.

Page 11 of the September 2015 [iOS Security White Paper](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) states that the file system key is stored in [NAND](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/NAND).

> The metadata of all files in the file system is encrypted with a random key, which is created when iOS is first installed or when the device is wiped by a user. The file system key is stored in Effaceable Storage.

> Effaceable Storage: A dedicated area of NAND storage, used to store cryptographic keys, that can be addressed directly and wiped securely. While it doesn’t provide protection if an attacker has physical 
>   possession of a device, keys held in Effaceable Storage can be used as part of a key hierarchy to facilitate fast wipe and forward security.